# I've been wasting or I've wasted?

Tags: tense, present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

Which tense is used in this sentence?

Oh no! This is the wrong paint! I _____________ a lot of time. Now I have to paint all the walls again!

A. Have been wasting
B. Have wasted

What's the right answer here? The answer key is "I have wasted" but couldn't it be "I have been wasting"?

Because the wasting just finished just then?

Comment: There's no "it". I mistranscribed it. Also it's present perfect or present perfect continuous.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Present perfect and Present perfect continuous in cases where action doesn't have any result](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/332963/what-is-the-difference-between-present-perfect-and-present-perfect-continuous-in)